# Where to use 11-digit generated hash key in SMS Retriever API?

Tags: android

I've all things setup in both server and android side. My flow is working fine. I generated hashkey also, but now don't know where to use it.

Note: I removed RECEIVE_SMS permission and now listener is not calling.

Code:

```
private void startSMSListener() {
    try {
        smsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
        smsReceiver.setOTPListener(this);

        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION);
        this.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);

        SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this);

        Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // API successfully started
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Fail to start API
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Update: I'm not getting OTP:
Server side code:

```
//Prepare Url
                OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://msg.msgclub.net/rest/services/sendSMS/sendGroupSms?AUTH_KEY="+authKey+"&message=<#>You OTP is:"+randomPIN+"TthI79n9NvR&senderId=REMIND&routeId=1&mobileNos="+mobNo+"&smsContentType=english")
                        .get()
                        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                        .build();
```

which logic should I try inside onReeive method? can anyone please guide me?
Code:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SmsRetriever;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.CommonStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.tekitsolution.remindly.Dialog.PaymentListDialog;
import com.tekitsolution.remindly.Listener.SMSListener;

public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = SMSReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    private SMSListener mListener;

    /**
     * @param mListener
     */
    public void setOTPListener(SMSListener mListener) {
        this.mListener = mListener;
    }


    /**
     * @param context
     * @param intent
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        showLog("Inside SMS Receiver");
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            Status status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);
            switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:

                    //This is the full message
                    String message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                    showLog("message: "+ message);
                    /*<#> Your ExampleApp code is: 123ABC78
                    FA+9qCX9VSu*/

                    //Extract the OTP code and send to the listener

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onOTPReceived(message);
                    }
                    break;


                case CommonStatusCodes.API_NOT_CONNECTED:

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onOTPReceivedError("API NOT CONNECTED");
                    }

                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.NETWORK_ERROR:

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onOTPReceivedError("NETWORK ERROR");
                    }

                    break;

                case CommonStatusCodes.ERROR:

                    if (mListener != null) {
                        mListener.onOTPReceivedError("SOME THING WENT WRONG");
                    }

                    break;

            }
        }
    }

    private void showLog(String msg) {
        Log.d(TAG, msg);
    }
}
```

OTP activity: called this method inside onCreate:

```
 private void startSMSListener() {
        try {
            smsReceiver = new SMSReceiver();
            smsReceiver.setOTPListener(this);

            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
            intentFilter.addAction(SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION);
            this.registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);

            SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this);

            Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
            task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                   showLog("success");
                }
            });

            task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    showLog("failure");
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AyushBansal yes, also please see the updated question.

Comment: You haven't registered your SMSReceiver with LocalBroadcastManager. I think you should do that

Comment: @AyushBansal please see updated code

Answer (score 0):

- Your sms format should be

<#> SampleApp: Your verification code is 143567
QbwSot12oP

**1) The message should start with <#>, that will indicate this is an OTP message to the system.**

**2) The message should end with Hashcode e.g QbwSot12oP at the end of the message.**

So you have to pass your generated hash to server and append it at last of this sms.

Following is the complete example of retrive api. I used it and it is working in my case

> https://medium.com/android-dev-hacks/autofill-otp-verification-with-latest-sms-retriever-api-73c788636783

Generate hash key pragmatically via AppSignatureHelper in given example. And pass it to your server and make message format like I show you before.

Comment: I'm not getting otp. Server side Impl format: //Prepare Url
                OkHttpClient client=new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://msg.msgclub.net/rest/services/sendSMS/sendGroupSms?AUTH_KEY="+authKey+"&message=You OTP is:"+randomPIN+"TthI79n9NvR&senderId=REMIND&routeId=1&mobileNos="+mobNo+"&smsContentType=english")
                        .get()
                        .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                        .build();

Comment: You are not getting OTP so something went wrong in your server side programming.  After getting sms SMS retrive api will work for auto fill OTP into Edittext

Comment: it was working fine before implemented auto retriver api. see the updated question

Comment: But there is no connection between SMS Retriver Api and OTP Receive process.

Comment: that code is server side. Atlease I should get otp in my phone.

Comment: Ok. So your Question is invalid. You provide code for SMS Retrive api. Ask New question.

Comment: my question is still same. Where to put this hashcode? and after putting why I'm not getting otp in my phone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200706/discussion-between-sohel-eco-and-priyanka-singh).

Comment: umm okay dear, come